# C: transposing matrix, segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, transpose

I'm having some trouble doing a matrix transpose question from a text book i'm 
learning C from.

When the code is run it outputs a huge amount of arbitrary figures followed by "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Upon looking at other answers to similar questions most of them involve pointers/flags, but the book has not reached that stage yet so the problem should be solved without them.

Q. Write a function transposeMatrix that takes as an argument a 4x5 matrix and a 5x4 matrix. Have the function transpose the 4x5 matrix and store the results in the 5x4 matrix. Also write a main routine to test the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void transposeMatrix (int matrix1[4][5], int matrix2[5][4])
{
int i, j;

for(i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        matrix2[j][i] = matrix1[i][j];
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    for(j = 0; j < 4; ++i) {
        printf("%i ", matrix2[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}

int main (void) 
{
void transposeMatrix (int matrix1[4][5], int matrix2[5][4]);
int imatrix2[5][4]; 

int imatrix1[4][5] = 
  { 
    {5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    {5, 4, 3, 2, 1},
    {9, 8, 7, 6, 5}
  };


transposeMatrix(imatrix1, imatrix2);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: At your first `for` loop, both loops use `i` which won't work. You need `j` also.

Comment: `void transposeMatrix (int matrix1[4][5], int matrix2[5][4]);` is unnecessary in `main()`.

Comment: And the second inner loop increases `i` when it should increase `j`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just used the wrong loop variables in a few places.  In the first loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
```

should be:

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for(j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
```

(i.e. change `i` to `j` in the inner loop.

Also, in the second loop, the following:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    for(j = 0; j < 4; ++i) {
```

should be:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    for(j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
```

(i.e. incrememt `j`, not `i`, in the inner loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        matrix2[j][i] = matrix1[i][j];
    }
}
```

Inner loop counter here should be j but you have used i, it is also making

```
matrix2[j][i] = matrix1[i][j];
```

This statement use uninitialized values of j which is leading to undefined behaviour